# How to keep a transform after changing centerX and centerY?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm implementing a drag behavior, and I am having the following problem.

I first scale a rectangle having the CenterX and CenterY equals 0. Then, I change the CenterX and CenterY at runtime to the up right corner of the rectangle to scale to the left side.

The problem is, when I change the centerX and centerY of the object, everthing is redrawn like I've never changed the CenterX and CenterY.

Obs: I am using RenderTransform.

I don't know if I explainned well =x.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Create a sample app that does only what you are talking about and post the xaml and code, then it might be easier for us to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code is hard to help. But I'll try anyway.

You can try using the transformation matrix for a "real result". example:

```
        Point dragDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);

        Matrix toCalculate = ((visualComponent as FrameworkElement).RenderTransform).Value;
        dragDelta = toCalculate.Transform(dragDelta);

        myData.X += dragDelta.X;
        myData.Y += dragDelta.Y;
```

There are many ways to do this. I do not particularly like to use translation transform. The ideal is to use thumbs and set via style using templates. This should help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF